# PDF Generation in ASP.NET MVC with TCPDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Basically I'm after advice on producing dynamic PDFs with charts, images and some styling into a view or partial view for the user to print or optionally download.

I've used TCPDF in the past, and so was wondering if there was any way to utilize my TCPDF php files to pass a generated PDF into a view?

I've also looked at ITextSharp, but I was worried about the lack of customization including dynamic charts that TCPDF has provided me in the past.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  Currently I'm attempting to install VS.PHP module for Visual Studio 2010, in the hope I can load the generated TCPDF file into a memorystream and pass it to a view (inline).

Is my logic totally wrong?  Please advise.

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I've added Phalanger (http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) to my project along with some tcpdf examples in my Content/reports folder.

my controller code was pretty simple (I got most of it from another post on the Phalanger forums):

```
        public ActionResult SummaryReport()
    {
        var context = PHP.Core.ScriptContext.CurrentContext;

        using (var request_context = PHP.Core.RequestContext.Initialize(PHP.Core.ApplicationContext.Default, System.Web.HttpContext.Current))
        {
            var output = request_context.ScriptContext.Include(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/reports/testoutput.php")), false);

            return Content("");
        }
     }
```

However I'm now receiving TCPDF Errors when the controller tries to execute the TCPDF example:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Invalid argument 'pattern':     u0192\u2039\u008D\u203A\u017E\u0178\u00A1-\u00BA] # AL | Ù[\u20AC-\u0160\u00AD-\u00AF\u00B1-\u00BF] # AL | Ú[\u20AC-\u00BF] # AL | Û[\u20AC-\u2022\u009D\u00A5\u00A6\u00AE\u00AF\u00BA-\u00BF] # AL | Ü[\u20AC-\u008D\u0090\u2019-\u00AF] # AL | Ý[\u008D-\u00AD] # AL | Þ[\u20AC-\u00A5\u00B1] # AL | ï­[\u0090-\u00BF] # AL | ï®[\u20AC-\u00B1] # AL | ï¯[\u201C-\u00BF] # AL | ï[\u00B0-\u00B3][\u20AC-\u00BF] # AL | ï´[\u20AC-\u00BD] # AL | ïµ[\u0090-\u00BF] # AL | ï¶[\u20AC-\u008F\u2019-\u00BF] # AL | ï·[\u20AC-\u2021\u00B0-\u00BC] # AL | ï¹[\u00B0-\u00B4\u00B6-\u00BF] # AL | ïº[\u20AC-\u00BF] # AL | ï»[\u20AC-\u00BC] ..." - [x-y] range in reverse order. in (MYPATH)\Content\reports\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 15859, column 7.

Warning: preg_match(): Invalid argument 'pattern': [x-y] range in reverse order. in (MYPATH)\Content\reports\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 15865, column 7.
```

Has anyone any idea how to overcome this?  I've taken the latest TCPDF at will most likely post on the TCPDF forum.  I fear if I can't get these working I will result to using a .NET PDF library as I'm under strict time constraints.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi yes I had a look at ABCpdf, and I'm aiming to implement a solution using their software or ItextSharp if the PHP option falls through.

Currently I'm almost there.. I'll post up my code for anyone interested.

Comment: I've decided to go with ABCpdf as it is cheaper and has alot of great documentation to help me produce the PDFs I require.

ElYusubov would you like to put your comment in as an answer and I'll accept it? :)

All that is left now is chart generation, but that's another topic entirely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at ABCpdf yet? 
It seems to be the suitable solution for you :)

ps: link is included in my comment